# Scanner assumes document feeder is legal-sized

Tags: linux, scanner, sane

I have a Brother MFC-J630W all-in-one printer-scanner-fax.  I have the sane software installed, along with the sane driver provided by Brother.  The scanner has a document feeder.

I'm using this command:

```
 scanimage --device-name "$device" --resolution 300 > $output_file
```

Everything was working well until I used the document feeder to scan a legal-sized page.  Now, if I put any letter-sized page into the document feeder, I end up with a legal-sized scan.

The biggest problem is, I don't (yet) know if this is a problem on the scanner side, or on the software side.  All I know for certain is that the pnm file created by scanimage is legal-sized.

Does anybody have any ideas for troubleshooting and/or fixing this problem?

Comment: You might want to try opening Xsane and changing the default scan settings for sane in there then trying a test scan.  (It also supports batch mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Brother A3 (MFC 6490CW) scanner and to scan A4 on that I use:

```
scanimage -x 209.981 -y 296.973 -l 43.496 --format=tiff \
    --batch=xx_00%03d.tif --batch-start=0
```

I had to experiment a bit to get the '-l' value right, my feeder is centered.

It takes a while before `scanimage` connect to the scanner and starts.

Comment: I think you're right.  I just found that scanimage tells me that the default value for -y is 355.6 mm, which is 14 inches.  So maybe it always worked that way and I just didn't notice.

Comment: This is not using the feeder for me. It's trying to scan multiple pages from the flatbed

Comment: @Marcel have you tried scanning/copyting/faxing using the built-in interface of the MFC-6490CW? Maybe the device doesn't detect that there is paper in the feeder.

Comment: I am able to scan from the feeder using python-sane or simple-scan.